# IE jumps to start of textarea after focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, textarea

I want to put "- " to textarea if it's empty. It works currently perfectly with Firefox and Chrome, but IE is giving me a headache. IE inserts that same just like other browsers but after that it jumps to start of textarea.

So other browsers get like this "- c" but IE "c- " // c=cursor

### Javascript

```
$('#textbox').focus(function(){
    if(this.value == "") {
       this.value = this.value + "- ";
          }
});
```

- What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cursor position explicitely like this,

```
$('#textbox').focus(function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
        this.value = this.value + "- ";
        this.setSelectionRange(1, 1);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdLwvmxp/60/)